# How to print variable name in function in C

Tags: c, variables

I want to print the name of a 2D matrix I take as input in a function.

I tried using this I found on the internet:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define VariableName(var) #var   

void saddle(int a[][100], int m, int n)
{
    printf("The saddle points of the matrix %s are: \n", VariableName(a));
}
 `
```

But on every function call I get the name as `a` instead of the matrix `I` entered, eg. `A`, `B`, or `C`.
How to get past this?

Comment: C passes values in function calls, not identifiers. You could pass in the function name, or pass in a matrix struct that contains a matrix name field and an array field.

Comment: The name of the variable passed to the function `saddle()` is not retained inside the function `saddle()` in the C language because C doesn't have a "pass by name". It does have "pass by value" but that doesn't retain the name of the passed variable. To get the effect you want, it would be necessary to use a preprocessor macro when `saddle()` is *called* rather than inside `saddle()`.

Comment: Change `void saddle(int a[][100], int m, int n)` to `void saddle(int a[][100], int m, int n, char* name)` and then call it with `void saddle(I, x, y, VariableName(I))`

Comment: You can hide all parameters except for the first one in a macro: `#define saddle(a) real_saddle(a, sizeof a / sizeof *a, sizeof *a / sizeof **a, VariableName(a))` and call it with `saddle(matrix);`: https://godbolt.org/z/xWdPzr5TT

Answer (score 4):

`VariableName(var)` always produces the string `"a"` in your code. The name of the matrix is only known at the calling site, so you should pass it as an extra argument and you can use the same macro there to create the string:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define VariableName(var) #var   

void saddle(int a[][100], int m, int n, const char *name)
{
    printf("The saddle points of the matrix %s are:\n", name);
}

int main(void)
{
    int matrix[100][100];
    saddle(matrix, 100, 100, VariableName(matrix));
    return 0;
}
```

Using `"matrix"` instead of `VariableName(matrix)` seems simpler, but here is a more advanced version where the matrix name or expression is passed implicitly:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define VariableName(var) #var   

#define saddle(a,m,n)  (saddle)(a, m, n, VariableName(a))
#define print_matrix(a,m,n)  (print_matrix)(a, m, n, VariableName(a))

void (saddle)(int a[][100], int m, int n, const char *name)
{
    printf("The saddle points of the matrix %s are:\n", name);
}

void (print_matrix)(int a[][100], int m, int n, const char *name)
{
    printf("Contents of matrix %s:\n", name);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; i++)
            printf(" %3d", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int matrix1[10][100] = { 0 };
    int matrix2[10][100] = { 0 };
    saddle(matrix1, 10, 10);
    saddle(matrix2, 10, 10);
    print_matrix(matrix1, 10, 10);
    print_matrix(matrix2, 10, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but it's useless anyway. `"matrix"` would be shorter than `VariableName(matrix)`

Comment: @phuclv But, `VariableName(...)` will be more generic and can be used widely, instead of hard-coding every variable's name. Also, as this is a macro, it will be computed at compile-time.

Comment: @phuclv when you automatically rename all occurences of the variable using an IDE, it will change `VariableName(matrix)` to the new name, but not `"matrix"`.

Comment: @mch I know but I don't fully trust IntelliSense to do that reliably in C or C++ because of the complexity of compilation units